# Should I be sending multiple tasks to MySQL at the same time? If so, how?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

If I have a loop which executes PDO statements, is there a way to collate those executions and run them after the loop in one go, or is it normal to execute each one individually?

For example, I am updating a field on every row in my database like this:

```
$pdo = new PDO(/* valid connnection arguments */);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, username, password FROM users ORDER BY id ASC");
$stmt->execute();

foreach($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS) as $user)
{
    $token = sha1($salt . $user->username . $user->password);

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET token = :token WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ":id" => $user->id,
        ":token" => $token
    ));
}
```

But I'm pretty confident this should be done differently, as one query to MySQL. I'm vaguely familiar with concatenating queries with `;` in phpMyAdmin, so I'm guessing that's the key, but I'm not sure how to do that in conjunction with prepared statements.

Comment: I know this doesn't help in this situation, but only need to `prepare` once.

Comment: @Mike You mean I can do one `prepare` with multiple `execute`s holding different data? I didn't know that, thanks. I always took it as preparing for the execution, after which the state is reset and you need to prepare again.

Comment: Yes, you just prepare once, then loop the binding and executing.

Comment: Please tell me those aren't in-the-clear unhashed passwords in that database table.

Comment: IMHO 'Collate' as you called it will help you only with inserts using multi-insert syntax. Other than that either try to write it as one statement if possible or stick to 'prepare once and execute multiple times'

Comment: @Thanatos They're not - and I don't think a lecture on security is going to add anything valuable to my question.

Comment: phpMyAdmin just split your queries by ';' and then run them separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it normal to execute each one individually?

Yes.
For such one-time tasks like one in question, it's all right with multiple queries. What you have to avoid is running large loops on a regular basis, as it doesn't really matter, if you can collide your statements or not - a database will have to run them all either way.

So, now you can run your massive update loop already and turn to more urgent matters.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback - I was assuming there was a way to batch multiple statements to avoid multiple requests to the database but if that's not the case I'm comfortable.

Answer (score 1):

You could let the database handle the update: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha1

```
UPDATE users SET token=sha1(token)
```

Comment: That is effective in this context (my sample is maybe a little broad) but doesn't answer the actual question.

Comment: @MartyWallace could you be a bit more specific about what you are trying to do then? I'm assuming jeff meant `UPDATE users SET token=sha1(CONCAT(:salt, username, password))` but was just simplifying it.